# recreate view programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, view, recreate

I'm calling the following code fragment to swap a view.(on top of screen, there's a `UISegmentedControl` to switch views)

```
SomeViewController* vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
self.view = vc.view;
```

When user can switch back to original view by clicking the first button on the `UISegmentedControl`.

How should I recreate the view?

Comment: if i m not wrong you should try to make singleton type of view, so you can achieve again as you left it.

Comment: i just give an idea that just hide and show the SomeViewController on segmentbutton click event.. and add as a subview of you main view..

Answer (score 0):

just for an example and for one idea if you use this bellow logic then its very easy to fullfil your requirement..

add as a subview of your `self.view` in `viewDidLoad:` method and hide it...

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChangedValue:(id)sender{
    if (segmentedControl.selectedIndex == 0) {
        vc.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (segmentedControl.selectedIndex == 1) {
        vc.hidden = NO;
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:vc];
    }
}
```